# Pushing up a new project code to new repository on github but it pushed up all new projects

Tags: git, github

I created a new repository on github, followed the commands for pushing up a new project from my local computer:

…or create a new repository on the command line

```
echo "# node-rest-shop" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin github@projectname
git push -u origin master
```

After I `git push -u origin master` I went to the github repo page and noticed that it pushed 3 of my other projects that are not related to this new one.

Why and how did this happen?

Comment: u need to cd into your project folder first before running those commands
delete .git and then cd and then try those again
this time do `git push -u origin master -f` to overriden previous content

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `git init` actually created a `.git` (hidden) subfolder in your `README.md` folder.

If a parent folder already had a `.git`, you might have pushed from a local repository larger that you though.

Answer (score 0):

To push existing project first time on git.

1. Open Terminal.
2. Change the current working directory to your local project.
3. Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.
   $ git init
4. Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the first   commit.
   $ git add.
5. Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository.$ git commit -m "First commit"
6. At the top of your GitHub repository's Quick Setup page, click to copy the remote repository URL. ￼
7. In Terminal, add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed.$ git remote add origin remote repository URL
   # Sets the new remote
   $ git remote -v
   # Verifies the new remote URL
8. Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.$ git push -u origin master
   # Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your folder structure. Did you do this in a new folder? If you forgot to do a new folder and cd into it, git probably picked up all your other repos in this directory and pushed them. The other possibility is that there already was a .git file, but then git should've thrown an error.